Certificate authority in known_hosts file not recognized - OpenSSH
I am working on establishing an SSH connection between a host server and a client using the SSH certificates, as a first step of the process I used the CA key (generated using a separate CA server) to sign the host public key (host_key.pub), this process generates the host_key-cert.pub and I also configured the sshd_config file adding the HostCertificate line.
As a 2nd step I wanted to make the client trust the hosts that have the key signed by CA, so i added the CA public key to the known_hosts file like this :
@cert-authority * ssh-rsa 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 badreddine1906@ubuntu-CA

I wanted to test if the client will trust the host before completing the signing of the user keys so I tried to log in to the server and see if that usual ssh msg of first time use would still pop up (it shoundl't normally since I added the CA public key to the known_hosts file so the client will automatically trust any host that presents a host_key signed by the CA) but the msg keeps popping up and asks me if I want to trust the host because it is unknown :

The authenticity of host 'ubuntu.server.ssh (10.10.10.20)' can't be
established. ED25519 key fingerprint is
SHA256:3nM02/5BE1HKfdLbtUHOurBiS4FGb7QY5ww1cCkhnR8. This key is not
known by any other names Are you sure you want to continue connecting
(yes/no/[fingerprint])?

the problem is that when I enter the -vvv flag to understand what is the issue, the error doesnt say unvalid certificate or some sort of thing
It seems like it doesnt even read the line in the known_hosts file for some reason :
badreddine1906@ubuntu-SSH-client:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvv ubuntu.server.ssh
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "ubuntu.server.ssh" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup ubuntu.server.ssh:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to ubuntu.server.ssh [10.10.10.20] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ubuntu.server.ssh:22 as 'badreddine1906'
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from ubuntu.server.ssh
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from ubuntu.server.ssh
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug3: kex_choose_conf: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:3nM02/5BE1HKfdLbtUHOurBiS4FGb7QY5ww1cCkhnR8
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from ubuntu.server.ssh
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from ubuntu.server.ssh
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying user hostfile "/home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying user hostfile "/home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts2"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/badreddine1906/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying system hostfile "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying system hostfile "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
The authenticity of host 'ubuntu.server.ssh (10.10.10.20)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:3nM02/5BE1HKfdLbtUHOurBiS4FGb7QY5ww1cCkhnR8.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

what might be the issue causing the client not to recognize the certificate( and i am sure that the CA is correct, otherwise if it wasnt correct an error would indicate an invalid certificate)

I solved the issue, in the sshd_config file even though I specified the HostCertificate but I didnt specify the HostKey (the host's private key "host_key" that was used to obtain the signed certified key "host_key-cert.pub")
The host was per default using another private key since it wasnt specified in the configuration and that's why the client didnt recognize the key
